# pulling information from a AJAX request, that returns a json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

so I'm trying to figure out how to use the returned json information.  I want to pull the city and state information, then reference the city, and state in an autofill concept elsewhere in my html. Problem is, I don't have an object to reference.

This is where I'm at so far, using a AJAX request

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
url: ("http://ZiptasticAPI.com/" + $("#zipcode").val()),
data: {},
success: function (resultdata) {
console.info(resultdata);}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: sorry, wrote it rather quick, I think I clarified it a bit

Comment: what do you get in resultdata?

Comment: {country: "US", state: "CA", city: "CANYON COUNTRY"}
city:"CANYON COUNTRY"
country:"US"
state:"CA"

Comment: What way you want to render in your HTML of? as table?

Comment: its all filling out a form, so I want to auto populate the city and state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fill a form with the data retrieved of the AJAX, depending of the type of data (if it is a input, checkbox, select, etc) option. As I see that you are using jQuery.

Example, to set the value to a input text:

```
$('input.foo').val(resultdata.city);
```

in case that input is select:

```
$("select").val(resultdata.state); // this only works if the value of the option is CA
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

After your console.log add this:

```
data = JSON.parse(resultdata); // declare data elsewhere to make available
```

You can then access it with

```
data.country
data.state ... etc
```

and use those values to populate your form.